# External conf file in perl module

Tags: perl, module, config

I'm pretty new in Perl and need an advice for this, please.

I have a script **Script.pl** in a "**Path 1**".
Beside, I have a module **ModuleA.pm** in a "**Path 2**".
Finally, I have a common module **ModuleB.pm** in a "**Path 3**". This ModuleB is common and other script in other path use it.
All path are differents. The Script.pl use the ModuleA, and the ModuleA use the ModuleB.

I need put a external file of configuration in the ModuleB. This conf file is in the same "Path 3". The conf.cfg is require in the ModuleB:

```
use strict;
require "conf.cfg";
```

How can I include the conf.cfg in the ModuleB as a dynamic way?, because if I compile the Script.pl, doesn't compile because can't find the conf.cfg, because now ModuleB path is "Path 1" and in the "Path 1" doesn't exist the conf file.

So I need require the conf file independently of the *.pl and path that use the ModuleB.

I was clear enough?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**   Added code to get the `ModuleB` path at runtime for `require`, to avoid hard-coding it since the module's location may be moved in updates (separate section at the end).

---

Specify the full path for `conf.cfg` when requiring it.

Consider the following hierarchy and files, where all paths start from `/path/`

```
/path/Path1/script.pl 
/path/Path2/ModuleA.pm 
/path/Path3/ModuleB.pm 
/path/Path3/conf.cfg
```

The main **script.pl**

```
use warnings;
use lib '/path';
use Path2::ModuleA;
```

File **Path2/ModuleA.pm**

```
package ModuleA;    
use warnings;
use Path3::ModuleB;
1;
```

File **Path3/ModuleB.pm**

```
package ModuleB;
use warnings;
require "Path3/conf.cfg";
1;
```

File **Path3/conf.cfg**

```
use feature 'say';
say "This is conf.cfg";
```

Running the `script.pl` (from inside `Path1/`) prints the line `This is conf.cfg`

---

Note the line `use lib '/path'`, where `/path` is a literal string specifying the path to directory from which `Path2` and `Path3` start. See [`lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) pragma

> It is typically used to add extra directories to perl's search path so that later use or require statements will find modules which are not located on perl's default search path.

Using library path relative to where the script is can be made easier. In `script.pl`

```
# Load relative path for modules.
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin/../lib";
use Path2::ModuleA;
# ...
```

In this case `Path2` (etc) for modules start in the directory `../lib`, relative to where the script is

```
./bin/script.pl
./lib/Path2/ModuleA.pm
./lib/Path3/...
```

where I picked the name `bin` just as an example.  See the core module [`FindBin`](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html).

This quick note barely scratches the surface of how modules can be organized.

---

A specific constraint emerged in comments. The `ModuleB` lives in a path that may change with future updates, thus hard-coding that path in the `require` statement is not optimal.

One solution is that the path is found inside `ModuleB` at runtime and that used in the `require`.  This can be done using Perl's *special literal* [`__FILE__`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values).

File **Path3/ModuleB.pm**

```
package ModuleB;

use warnings;
use strict;
use Cwd qw(abs_path);    

my ($this_dir) = abs_path(__FILE_) =~ m|(.*)/|;

require "$this_dir/conf.cfg";

1;
```

The `abs_path` from the core module [`Cwd`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html) is needed since `__FILE__` may not return the absolute path. The regex used to find the directory itself matches everything up to a `/` *greedily*, all the way up to the last `/` -- thus the whole path without the filename itself.  Instead of doing that you can use functions from either of the [`File::Spec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) or [`File::Basename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) core modules.

Comment: @h3g0r_ I am not certain that I understand the problem, please let me know whether this helps and if I need to add or explain.

Comment: that's the problem. But, my scenario is different because I can't modify all the script (.pl) that use the ModuleB. For that cause I want to modify only the ModuleB. I want to "include" or "require" the conf file in the ModuleB independent of those who use. Somethings like a "pwd" of the moduleB.pm as file. Can I do that? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @h3g0r_ Ah. So you can only edit ModuleB, is that correct? What is the actual hierarchy?  You don't need to touch script.pl if the paths can be found once it's executed -- just supply the full path when you `require` the config file.  Did you try the above, with `require "Path3/conf.cfg"` as the only to change to whatever you have?

Comment: Yes, I must only modify the ModuleB, because is not possible modify all the script that use ModuleB. The hierarchy is similar to you said:   /admin/process1/Script.pl
/admin/process1/lib/ModuleA.pm
/admin/perlmod/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/common/ModuleB.pm      The idea of this is not put the full path in the module, the real path as a string, because in some moment the perl lib will be upagrade and the 5.10.1 will be 5.12.0 and then I must change again the ModuleB to fix the reference.

Comment: @h3g0r_OK.  I added one way to do that. The path for `ModuleB` (and thus `conf.cfg`) can be found at runtime, and that used in `require` (which goes at runtime, not at BEGIN). It's added to the end of the post.